# What is the meaning of "store-testing"?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

I would like to know what is the meaning of the term **store-testing** as seen in the commercial ad below.

Is there a verb "to store-test"? What does it mean?

[image]

It seems merriam-webster does not have this word "store-test"

Comment: What a horrible ad! Where did you find it?

Comment: @terdon: in the 1950s, by the look of it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet well yes, I did not think it was recent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It quite simply means testing the flavour of the coffee in the store before buying it, so as to avoid coming home with a coffee that looks good, but really tastes bad. It’s not (as far as I know) a set phrase, but a more generic equivalent of trying on clothes in the store before buying them.

Comment: This comes from an era in which the US was switching to much more prepackaged products, and away from bulk commodity products.  *Store-testing* (sniffing the coffee beans in the case or barrel) was no longer so easily done. The newly *liberated* wife bore the risks of not having been more involved in the careful catering to her husbands whims.